# Are immutable "lookup" arrays a good choice in a base encoding algorithm?

Tags: haskell, optimization, encoding

context: I am making a haskell program that implements  base 2 4 8 16 32 64 and 128 encodings of ByteString terms, It could be used very often in network context so I want it to be as fast and reliable as possible.

problem : My first implementation did encoding by performing recursive operations on each byte of data, this doesn't seem optimal at all to me so in my next try I wanted to use n dimensional arrays (maybe Judy arrays?) where each block of n Word8 terms is an index to its encoded version.
example : in base 64 encoding, each block of 3 Word8 values are an index to 4 Word8 values.

question: Is using immutable arrays in this context the best choice in regards to speed?

Comment: There are 2^24 `(Word8, Word8, Word8)` triples. So unless your input texts are 3*2^24 `Word8`s long or longer (48MiB!), precomputing the lookup table will probably be more expensive than normal-computing one element for every third position in the text. Laziness helps a little bit here, but I strongly encourage you to double-check that this refactor actually helps once you've got it implemented.

Comment: Since this is a micro-optimization (in other words, there are no asymptotic gains), try it and *profile*!  In this area, abstract knowledge only goes so far.

Comment: there exists [`base64-bytestring`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-bytestring) written by brian o'sullivan, his packages are know for being fast - so maybe you can look at his implementation and add other encodings or at least make sure you  measure your implementation against his!